# Stroke around (and inside) complex HTML canvas shape?

Tags: html5-canvas

I have some code that takes a array of colors and creates a grid of rectangles on a canvas based on the data:
https://jsfiddle.net/yzjeLm5r/2/

Html:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100">
  This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
</canvas>
```

Js:

```
var my_canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
  context = my_canvas.getContext("2d");

const cellSize = 20;
const arr = ['#FF0000', '#FF0000', null, null, '#0000FF',
  '#FF0000', '#FF0000', '#FF0000', null, '#0000FF',
  '#FF0000', null, '#FF0000', null, '#0000FF',
  '#FF0000', '#FF0000', '#FF0000', null, '#0000FF',
  '#FF0000', '#FF0000', '#0000FF', '#0000FF', '#0000FF'
]

let col = 0;
let row = 0;
arr.forEach((item) => {
  if (item) {
    context.fillStyle = item;
    context.fillRect(
      col * cellSize,
      row * cellSize,
      cellSize,
      cellSize
    );
  }
  if (col === 4) {
    col = 0;
    row += 1;
  } else {
    col += 1;
  }
});
```

Outcome:

[image]

I now need to find a way to create a stroke around the entire shape, as well as any 'island' pieces on the inside, to separate it from the blank regions (it does not separate the red from blue, just the outer borders). So it would look like this:

[image]

However, I can't find any viable way to do this. Some methods suggest creating the stroke, change the composition to `context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";` and then adding the fill which would 'merge' any overlapping pieces, but these don't actually overlap they just touch. Other solutions recommend just tracing around the edges of the complete shape with stoke `ctx.moveTo()` and then applying stroke, but since I'm filling data using fillRect() I dont have the coordinates to trace around it.

Is there anyway to get the stroke I need?

Comment: You should look for a "non-canvas" solution to approach this problem, forget about globalComposite and do this yourself ... post back when you have tried something

Comment: @HelderSepulveda I'm not sure what you mean by non-canvas solution, as in use a non-built in approach or to drop canvas all together? I'm using [pixel-art-react package](https://github.com/jvalen/pixel-art-react) as a base for my project that uses canvas under the hood, so the solution would either need to be a canvas solution or the whole project will need reworking. I have tried a few things (globalComposite and tracing the shape with hardcoded coords) but don't work for the reasons stated. I can accept "it's not possible" as an answer but I'm out of other ideas to try.

Comment: Certainly possible, just draw the border lines yourself when applicable

Answer (score 1):

Assuming its the inside edges the following as some solutions.

The simplest way is to render the borders by checking the 4 sides of each cell and drawing the border if the edge has a neighboring cell.

### If only 1 pixel

The next example adds the border and cell color in one pass, it is drawn twice, with the second (right) with only 1 pixel border.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const cells = 
    "AAA B" +
    "A A B" +
    "AAA B" +
    "AA BB" +
    "ABB B" +
    "AABBB"; 
const cols = {
    A: "#F00",
    B: "#00F",
};
const cols1 = {
    A: "#FDD",
    B: "#DDF",
};
const stride = 5;
const size = canvas.height / (cells.length / stride | 0);

const borderCol = "#000";
function drawCells(x, y, border, cols, cells) {
    var i = 0;
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,x,y);
    while (i < cells.length) {
        const col = cols[cells[i]];
        if (col) {
            const x = i % stride, y = i / stride | 0;
            ctx.fillStyle = col;
            ctx.fillRect(x * size, y * size, size, size);
            ctx.fillStyle = borderCol;
            const left = x ? cells[i - 1] : undefined;
            const right = x < stride - 1 ? cells[i + 1] : undefined;
    
            const s = size, b = border;
    
            !cols[cells[i - stride]] && ctx.fillRect(x * s, y * s, s, b);   // above
            !cols[cells[i + stride]] && ctx.fillRect(x * s, (y + 1) * s - b, s, b); // below
            !cols[left] && ctx.fillRect(x * s, y * s, b, s);
            !cols[right] && ctx.fillRect((x + 1) * s - b, y * s, b, s);
        }
        i++;
    }
}
drawCells(0, 0, 6, cols, cells);
drawCells(300, 0, 1, cols1, cells);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="240"></canvas>
```

However it does not do a good job on the inside corners.

### Fix the inside corners

To do that you can use a similar double pass. First pass draws the cells, then the second pass extends the borders for the top and bottom edges while using composite operation "source-atop" to ensure it only draws where there are existing pixels.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const cells = 
    "AAA BB" +
    "A AAAB" +
    "AAA BB" +
    "A  BBB" +
    "ABBB B" +
    "AA BBB"; 
const cols = {
    A: "#0C0",
    B: "#FF0",
};

const stride = 6;
const size = canvas.height / (cells.length / stride | 0);
const border = 6; // border width in pixels
const borderCol = "#000";

function drawCells(cells) {
    var i = 0;
    while (i < cells.length) {
        const col = cols[cells[i]];
        if (col) {
            const x = i % stride, y = i / stride | 0;
            ctx.fillStyle = col;
            ctx.fillRect(x * size, y * size, size, size);
        }
        i++;
    }
    ctx.fillStyle = borderCol;
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop";
    i = 0;
    while (i < cells.length) {
        const col = cols[cells[i]];
        if (col) {
            const x = i % stride, y = i / stride | 0;
            const left = x ? cells[i - 1] : undefined;
            const right = x < stride - 1 ? cells[i + 1] : undefined;
            const s = size, b = border, sb = s + b + b;
            !cols[cells[i - stride]] && ctx.fillRect(x * s - b, y * s, sb, b);
            !cols[cells[i + stride]] && ctx.fillRect(x * s - b, (y + 1) * s - b, sb, b);
            !cols[left] && ctx.fillRect(x * s, y * s, b, s);
            !cols[right] && ctx.fillRect((x + 1) * s - b, y * s, b, s);
        }
        i++;
    }
}
drawCells(cells);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="240" height="240"></canvas>
```

### Add a bevel

Or same again but using beveled corners

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const cells = 
    "AAA BB" +
    "A AAAB" +
    "AAA BB" +
    "A  BBB" +
    "ABBB B" +
    "AA BBB"; 
const cols = {
    A: "#F00",
    B: "#FF0",
};

const stride = 6;
const size = canvas.height / (cells.length / stride | 0);
const border = 6; // border width in pixels
const borderCol = "#000";
function bevelRectBottom(x, y, w, h) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineTo(x, y + h);
    ctx.lineTo(x + h, y);
    ctx.lineTo(x + w - h, y);
    ctx.lineTo(x + w, y + h);
    ctx.fill();
}
function bevelRectTop(x, y, w, h) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    ctx.lineTo(x + h, y + h);
    ctx.lineTo(x + w - h, y + h);
    ctx.lineTo(x + w, y);
    ctx.fill();
}
function drawCells(cells) {
    var i = 0;
    while (i < cells.length) {
        const col = cols[cells[i]];
        if (col) {
            const x = i % stride, y = i / stride | 0;
            ctx.fillStyle = col;
            ctx.fillRect(x * size, y * size, size, size);
        }
        i++;
    }
    ctx.fillStyle = borderCol;
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop";
    i = 0;
    while (i < cells.length) {
        const col = cols[cells[i]];
        if (col) {
            const x = i % stride, y = i / stride | 0;
            const left = x ? cells[i - 1] : undefined;
            const right = x < stride - 1 ? cells[i + 1] : undefined;
            const s = size, b = border, sb = s + b + b;
            !cols[cells[i - stride]] && bevelRectTop(x * s - b, y * s, sb, b);
            !cols[cells[i + stride]] && bevelRectBottom(x * s - b, (y + 1) * s - b, sb, b);
            !cols[left] && ctx.fillRect(x * s, y * s, b, s);
            !cols[right] && ctx.fillRect((x + 1) * s - b, y * s, b, s);
        }
        i++;
    }
}
drawCells(cells);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="240" height="240"></canvas>
```